# How to random shuffle all rows of a large table in bigquery dataset?

Tags: google-bigquery

Memory needed for a query like `"select id from table order by rand()"` will exceed allotted memory, and thus results in failure of the query. How can I get a random permutation of all rows from a pretty large table? The size of table is over 1 billion rows.

Comment: Can you give us an idea why you think you need it? What is your real use-case?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion！I do vote up every helpful reply that I received. However, my upvotings are not shown to other users because of the low reputation or something else of mine.

Comment: Business of our team requires to sample from the whole dataset repeatedly. The sample size varies each time from 80 million to 100k, and each sample is not expected to be duplicated with other recent samples. We have over 1 billion rows to manipulate, and dedupe every time I need to sample from the dataset is tiring.

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for clarifying  - make sense. see the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Business of our team requires to sample from the whole dataset repeatedly. The sample size varies each time from 80 million to 100k ...

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and uses table with 12+ billion rows, so should work for you too :o)

The pattern for query is:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT start_position 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.genomics_rice.Rice3K_DeepVariant_Os_Nipponbare_Reference_IRGSP_1_0`
WHERE MOD(CAST(<total number of rows in table> * RAND() AS INT64), <ratio of sample>) = 1
```

Formally  = CAST( /  AS INT64)
And in place of `1` in `= 1` - can be any integer between 0 and `<ratio of sample> - 1`

So for sample of 100K - you can use

```
#standardSQL
SELECT start_position 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.genomics_rice.Rice3K_DeepVariant_Os_Nipponbare_Reference_IRGSP_1_0`
WHERE MOD(CAST(12186710727 * RAND() AS INT64), 121867) = 1
```

Above returned 99,770 sampled rows in 8 seconds

And for sample of 80M - you can use

```
#standardSQL
SELECT start_position 
FROM `bigquery-public-data.genomics_rice.Rice3K_DeepVariant_Os_Nipponbare_Reference_IRGSP_1_0`
WHERE MOD(CAST(12186710727 * RAND() AS INT64), 152) = 1
```

returned 80,175,660 sampled rows in 13 seconds